# How to counter knife attack

Tags: battlefield-4

As the topic says. How can I counter the knife attack? I've read about it somewhere and saw a video, but I still can't figure out how to counter the knife.

Like to the video:

Comment: Likes in Bf3 Someone tryes to knife you If he cant and you press f you will do counter knife

Comment: I've only managed to counter once, and have been countered. From my one experience it was a context trigger, which popped up on the screen; to mash `F`. The other times I didn't even get a chance.

Comment: IMHO the question that was asked in October **2013** can not be called a duplicate of a question asked in February **2017**

Comment: Yup, close the other one or merge them.

Comment: The following meta is relevant: [On ending Chronological Oppression with respect to the matter of Question Duplication](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/)

Comment: The newer question clearly has a much better answer.  This dupe should stay.

Answer (score 2):

From [this site](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/706551-battlefield-4/66939784) it seems that all you have to do is counter it from the front. The video below goes into further detail about it.

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't try it myself so far, as far as I know it actually works similar to dropping flares: When you see the knifing animation, try hitting <kbd>X</kbd> to attempt countering it. If you time it right, you can knife the person trying to knife you, however I'm not sure how/if the actual attacking angle plays into this (which might be true).

Answer (score 0):

I have done it a few times now.It can only be done if you turn around mid knife and the counter knife button appears. If you get knifed from behind it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to see the attacker at least in the edge of the screen and the counter prompt comes up. If attacked from behind it can not be countered